# setEnvironment method is undefined for the ASTParser class

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am currently working with the AST of the JDT in order to be able to parse Java source code.  I need to identify the type bindings of parameters.  For example, for a String parameter, I would need to have java.lang.String and not simply String.

From some research I learnt that this may be done using resolveBinding but to do so one would need to set the environment using the setEnvironment method defined in the ASTParser.  For some reason though, Eclipse is indicating a compile-time error saying that setEnvironment is undefined for ASTParser.  I need the setEnvironment method because I do not have an IJavaProject available.

Can anyone please indicate what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry I havn't replied promptly but I wasn't notified.  I think my problem is that I am using JLS3 and not JLS4 like you did in the code snippet.  Could this be the problem?  I have managed to work my way around this problem but it would be better if I manage to obtain the full name of a type.  Thanks a lot for the interest @Templar

Comment: BTW, I am building a standalone application not a plug-in

Comment: No JLS3 is not a problem, could you show what errors you are getting? Or/and your code snippet, maybe there's a problem. Also you should get notified after any answer to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an Eclipse plug-in? If yes then you should be able to resolve bindings. Or maybe you are creating a standalone application using AST from Eclipse JDT? It is not clear. Also it would be useful if you could provide some code snippets where it fails.

I have developed some stand alone application and `setEnvironment` works fine using with `ASTParser`, here's a code snippet:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
// you must set compilation unit name, so I just name it as a path to source file
parser.setUnitName(inputFilePath.toString());
//params classpathEntries,  sourcepathEntries, encodings, IncludeRunningVMBootclasspath
parser.setEnvironment(null, null, null, true);
//fileContent is a char array of some source code
parser.setSource(fileContent);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

Afterwards having `CompilationUnit` you can traverse down the tree and find required nodes and use `resolveTypeBinding()` to get `ITypeBinding` object and then use `getQualifiedName()` to get a full name of a type, i.e. as you mentioned `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the .setEnvironment method using the following jar file: org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.10.0.v20140604-1726.jar. In addition, I added this set of jar files in this [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am3WpmEXpcZF2i4TkA3RgVQ7kqVr) to my classPath.

Comment: I tried using following this tutorial http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/how-to-resolve-bindings-when-using-eclipse-jdt-astparser/ and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem I faced while using maven repository of eclipse.jdt.core with version 3.7. Indeed this method is not supported in the previous versions. So using a newer version 3.10(+).x will be beneficial in this scope.